# Getting replication status for snapshot replication

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, replication

Is there a way we can get stats on how the snapshot replication is working in an easier report format to check on actually how many objects like tables or sps have been replicates followed by health to check if snapshot replication is actually working as expected

Publisher is Sql 2008r2
Subscriber is sql 2012

Answer (score 0):

Replication Monitor does this for me. You can see the current status, the status of past sessions and the details of which articles got delivered/copied.